# where does the git and mvn command go in mac/Linux?

Tags: linux, git, bash, command-line, command

I have installed `git` and `maven` on my mac. I know it works. but I am curious to see where these commands are found

Usual  commands such as `mv,ls,cd` are found in `/bin`. I do not find `git`,`maven`,`grep` in `/bin`. I do not have `.bashrc nor .bash_profile`. I do not see them in `env` too.

where I can see them?

Comment: Try `which git`, `which maven`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my Ubuntu:

```
$ which git
/usr/bin/git

$ which mvn
/usr/bin/mvn

$ which grep
/bin/grep
```

`which` should work on Mac OS X.

`whereis` is also a good option. From my ubuntu:

```
$ whereis git
git: /usr/bin/git /usr/share/man/man1/git.1.gz

$ whereis mvn
mvn: /usr/bin/mvn /usr/share/man/man1/mvn.1.gz

$ whereis grep
grep: /bin/grep /usr/share/man/man1/grep.1.gz
```

Comment: The POSIX command `type` should be included, perhaps even as the preferred option.

Comment: Right. However, `type` would give some other info for commands that are alias'd. On my ubuntu `type grep` says `grep is aliased to 'grep --color=auto'` whereas `which grep` give the required information. This is strictly with respect to the question raised by OP. On the other hand, I have been `TYPE'ing` for a long time :)

Comment: `bash` provides several options to `type` in addition to the POSIX-specified behavior, allowing it to function more like `which`.